# JavaFX custom controller factory

Tags: javafx-2, fxml, controller-factory

I have been experimenting with the `FXMLLoader` and using the `setControllerFactory` method using a custom `Callback<P,R>` implementation.

[The ORACLE documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/fxml_get_started/whats_new.htm#CHDDDDCC) says the following:

> An implementation might return a null value to indicate that it does
>   not or cannot create a controller of the given type; in this case, the
>   default controller construction mechanism will be employed by the
>   loader.

The result I want to achieve is that I can use a dependency injection framework to create any controllers that require parameters but I will let the `FXMLLoader` load any controllers that do not require parameters.

So if I have the following simple FXML file which uses the `ViewController` class which accepts no parameters...

```
<StackPane fx:id="pane"
          xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml"
          fx:controller="my.package.ViewController">
</StackPane>
```

and I use the following simple controller factory implementation to signal to the `FXMLLoader` that I want it to manage the construction of the controller in this case...

```
loader.setControllerFactory(new Callback<Class<?>, Object>(){
    @Override
    public Object Call(Class<?> type) {
        return null; // Let the FXMLLoader handle construction...
    }
});
```

after calling the `load()` method my Initialise method in the `ViewController` class is never called (I have verified this with a breakpoint).

If I change my controller factory implementation to return an instance of the `ViewController` class then everything works as expected.

Can anyone help me to clear up my confusion? Am I using the `Callback` interface incorrectly or is the ORACLE documentation incorrect?

Comment: Which version of JavaFX you are using? As the oracle's quoted description says, it may be valid for version 2.1, since the method to override is `getController(Class<?> type)` in there, while it is `call(Class<?> param)` in 2.2. So the behavior may also be changed, try with version 2.1.

Comment: I'm using version 2.2. I had noticed the difference in the callback syntax but assumed that was all that had changed since there was no mention of it in the 2.2 documentation. It's not a major problem as I can just use the dependency injection framework to create the controllers that do not have parameters in their constructors.

Comment: Here is [FXMLLoader JavaFX 8 source code](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/8/master/rt/file/tip/modules/fxml/src/main/java/javafx/fxml/FXMLLoader.java). Although it is not 2.2 but the most of their codes are similar. The only usage of controllerFactory is `setController(controllerFactory.call(type));`. So it maybe the same in 2.2. Just curious which DI framework are you using?

Comment: I'm planning on using Google Guice but I hadn't got that far yet as I was just evaluating the behaviour of the `FXMLLoader` and the controller factory callback.

Comment: if it is null, don't return `null`, instead, return `type.newInstance();`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

javafx does the following in FXMLLoader:

```
    try {
      if (controllerFactory == null) {
        setController(ReflectUtil.newInstance(type));
      } else {
        setController(controllerFactory.call(type));
      }
    } catch (InstantiationException exception) {
      throw new LoadException(exception);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException exception) {
      throw new LoadException(exception);
    }
```

so, yes, the oracle tutorial is incorrect.

Comment: Is this from version 2.2 or from version 8 as posted in the comments by Uluk Biy?